# почему discord бот не работает

Tags: c#, discord, .net-core

я использую библиотеку Discord.Net и Discord.Net.WebSocket

при запуске бота мне пишет:

You're using the GuildScheduledEvents gateway intent without listening to any events related to that intent, consider removing the intent from your config.

You're using the GuildInvites gateway intent without listening to any events related to that intent, consider removing the intent from your config.

код

```
class Program
{
DiscordSocketClient client;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    =>new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

private async Task MainAsync()
    {
        client = new DiscordSocketClient();
        client.Log += Log;
        var token = "";
        await client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot,token);
        await client.StartAsync();
    }

   private Task Log(LogMessage msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg.Message);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: У `Discord.net` сейчас, скажем так, новое перерождение, ибо этот проект долгое время не обновлялся "официально", он развивался путем сторонней библиотеки (`Discord.Net.Labs`), которую (вроде как) разрабатывал энтузиаст. Относительно недавно появился автор оригинальной библиотеки, который объединил наработки `Labs` со своим творением, выпустив `Discord.Net v3`, а вот документацию пока не обновил. Но хотяб есть [это](https://discordnet.dev/guides/v2_v3_guide/v2_to_v3_guide.html), где и описана ваша проблема. Короче, будьте готовы к тому, что в документации местами будет старая информация.

Comment: благодарю вас за ответ.